# Laravel-Displaying one to many relationship in view

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5.1

I am currently adding a feature to my website that asks questions and gives multiple choice answers.

My Answer Model has code like:

```
protected $table = 'answer';
protected $primaryKey = 'answer_id';
protected $fillable = ['question_id'];


 public function question()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Question','question_id')->distinct();
}
```

and my view is like:

```
@foreach ($answers as $answer)



<h2>{{$answer->question->question}}</h2>

  <p>{{$answer->answer}}</p>

@endforeach
```

My controller is:

```
     $answers = Answer::with('question')->first()->get();
```

It is displaying like:

question1

answer here

question1

answer here 2

question1

answer here 3

question2

2 answer here

question2

2 answer here 2

question2

2 answer here 3

I want to only show the question once. I am new to Laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flip this then, and first get your questions from the DB:

```
$questions = Question::with('answers')->get();
```

This of course assumes you've already setup a `hasMany` relationship in your Question model.

Then in your view you'll have two loops:

```
@foreach ($questions as $question)
    <h2>{{$question->question}}</h2>

    @foreach ($question->answers as $answer)     
        <p>{{$answer->answer}}</p>
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Note how you first loop through questions and display the question once, then loop through the answers for each question.

Comment: It is printing all the questions now but with one answer each.
question1

question1-answer here

question2
question1-answer here 2

question3
question1-answer here 3

question4
question2- answer here

question5
question2- answer here 2

question6
question2-answer here 3

Would it be how this is set up?

public function answer() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer','answer_id');
    }

Comment: Do a `dd($questions)` in your controller and examine your database results. Make sure your relationship is correct, and that you are getting the results you expect before troubleshooting the view.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It was my relationships! :) The code you supplied works perfectly too!!